# Migrating OpenProject database from package install to docker container

Tags: docker, postgresql

I've seen a few  people migrating OpenProject from a container to a package install, but not the other way around.  OpenProjects instructions for migrating assume you are moving from container to container or package to package install.

Exporting the postgres database on a package install is simple:

```
$  sudo openproject run backup
```

...which leaves:

```
attachments-<date>.tar.gz
conf-20200226142943.tar.gz
postgresql-dump-20200226142943.pgdump
```

in /var/db/openproject/backup

But then what?  The instructions on this page (https://docs.openproject.org/installation-and-operations/operation/restoring/#restoring-the-database) only explain how to import to a container from a container, not from a package install.

Anybody do this before?  Seems like it should be easy, I'm just not getting it.

Comment: A big help/thing that tripped me up was not passing `DATABASE_URL` but `POSTGRES_DATABASE_URL` to my Docker Env.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some quick notes on how I did it:

- Compared a PostgreSQL Docker Container vs the Live files and moved a few files from docker to the OP setup, such as `pg_hba.conf` & `postgresql.conf`
- Didn't import/export DB but moved actual files and then just pointed PSQL/OP Containers to the files
- I used another `httpd` container to proxy frontend for SSL and left the OP container config default

Here is some general code!

```
version: '3.2'

services:
  openproject:
    image: openproject/community:${OP_VER}
    container_name: openproject
    hostname: openproject
    networks:
      - openprojectnet
    depends_on:
      - opdb
#      - ophttpd
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: /opt/op/assets/
        target: /var/openproject/assets

    ports:
      - '8080:8080'

    environment:
      - 'TZ=${TZ}'
      - 'SECRET_KEY_BASE=${SECRET_KEY_BASE}'
      - 'EMAIL_DELIVERY_METHOD=${EMAIL_DELIVERY_METHOD}'
      - 'SMTP_ADDRESS=${SMTP_ADDRESS}'
      - 'SMTP_PORT=${SMTP_PORT}'
      - 'SMTP_DOMAIN=${SMTP_DOMAIN}'
      - 'SMTP_AUTHENTICATION=${SMTP_AUTHENTICATION}'
      - 'SMTP_ENABLE_STARTTLS_AUTO=${SMTP_ENABLE_STARTTLS_AUTO}'
      - 'SMTP_USER_NAME=${SMTP_USER_NAME}'
      - 'SMTP_PASSWORD=${SMTP_PASSWORD}'
      - 'DATABASE_URL=${POSTGRES_DATABASE_URL}' #Forced 'External DB Server
      - 'SERVER_HOSTNAME=${SERVER_HOSTNAME}'
#      - 'OPENPROJECT_EDITION=${OPENPROJECT_EDITION}' = Community/Std etc

  opdb:
    container_name: openproject_sql
    hostname: openprojectsql
    networks:
      - openprojectnet
    image: postgres:${PGSQL_VER}
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: /opt/op/psql/
        target: /var/lib/postgresql/data

    environment:
      - 'POSTGRES_USER=${DB_USER}'
      - 'POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DB_PWD}'
      - 'POSTGRES_DB=${DB_NAME}'
      - 'POSTGRES_ENCODING=UTF8'
      - 'POSTGRES_COLLATE=C'
      - 'POSTGRES_COLLATE_TYPE=C'


  ophttpd:
    container_name: httpd
    image: httpd
    ports:
      - '80:80'
      - '443:443'
    volumes:
      - type: volume #Even tho no html files are served, must define html volume as its required in base httpd image
        source: html
        target: /usr/local/apache2/htdocs
      - type: bind   # Comment this out, run container, and pull files from dir to host, then uncomment
        source: /opt/op/httpd/ # docker cp httpd:/usr/local/apache2/conf/ /opt/httpd/
        target: /usr/local/apache2/conf/

    environment:
      - 'TZ=${TZ}'

networks:
  openprojectnet:
    driver: bridge

#None of these volumes are used, just required by base image, all data is using BIND
volumes:
  html:
```

---

```
#Assets
#Run on Old_PROD
tar -zcvf /root/op_migrate/op_vardb.tgz /var/db/openproject/
scp /root/op_migrate/op_vardb.tgz root@192.168.1.255:/root/op_migrate/op_vardb.tgz

#SQL
#Run on Old_PROD
tar -zcvf /root/op_migrate/op_psql.tgz /var/lib/postgresql/13/main/
scp /root/op_migrate/op_psql.tgz root@192.168.1.255:/root/op_migrate/op_psql.tgz

#Assets
#Run on New_Prod
cd /root/op_migrate/
rm /opt/op/assets/* -R

tar -zxvf op_vardb.tgz
cp var/db/openproject/* /opt/op/assets/ -R
rm var -R

#SQL
#Run on New_Prod
cd /root/op_migrate/
rm /opt/op/psql/* -R

tar -zxvf op_psql.tgz
cp var/lib/postgresql/13/main/* /opt/op/psql/ -R
rm var -R
rm /opt/op/psql/*.pid
cp /opt/op/setup/sql/pg_hba.conf /opt/op/psql/
cp /opt/op/setup/sql/postgresql.conf /opt/op/psql/
cp /opt/op/setup/sql/.pgpass /root/.pgpass
```